# Asymptotic value of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I evaluate the integral

$$ n \int_0^1 t^{r-1}(2t-t^2)^{n-1}(2-2t) dt$$

I get the following :

$$2^{(-1 + 2 n)}\,n\,t^{(-1 + r)}(\mathsf{Beta}(1/2, n+r-1, n) - 4 (\mathsf{Beta}(1/2, r + n, n))$$

where $(\mathsf{Beta}(x,a,b)=\int_0^x u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1} du$

is the incomplete beta integral.

I want to know whether Mathematica can give me intermediate steps and,more importantly, how I can get the asyptotic limit of the value of the integral as $n$ approches infinity.

Comment: Something is wrong with your input. `n` does not appear inside the integral.

Comment: Please post the code you used as text. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: The `AsymptoticIntegrate` command fails with it. The required asymptotics can be found by [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). Ask it at MSE.

Comment: Integrate by part.

Comment: Your result still contains t, the integration variable...(cannot be). The limit n->Infinity of the expression containing incomplete Beta functions seems hard to calculate, plotting @m_goldberg 's result suggests the limit approaches 1 from below if r>1 and from above if r<1

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but a request for user64494 that can not be put in a comment to the question.

When I use Mathematica 12.1 to evaluate

```
n Integrate[t^(r - 1) (2 t - t^2)^(n - 1) (2 - 2 t), {t, 0, 1}]
```

which is your integral expressed properly in the Wolfram Language, I get

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[
>    2^(-1 + 2 n + r) n (Beta[1/2, -1 + n + r, n] - 2 Beta[1/2, n + r, n]),
>    Re[n + r] > 1]
> ```

which is ***not*** the result you show. Can you clarify your question to reconcile your result with mine? Please use the Wolfram Language when you make the clarification.

Comment: Execute `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 n*t^(r - 1)*(2 t - t^2)^(n - 1)*(2 - 2 t), {t, 0, 1}, {n, Infinity, 
  1}, Assumptions -> Re[r] > -1 && n > 1]`. The condition `Re[r]>-1&&n>1`  guaranttes  the convergence at $t=0$. After integration by part the `AsymptoticIntegrate ` command  results in `n^(-1 - r/
  2) (-1 + r) (1/2 n Gamma[r/2] - 
   1/16 (2 r + r^2) Gamma[r/
     2] + ((16 r + 36 r^2 + 20 r^3 + 3 r^4) Gamma[r/2])/(768 n))`.

Comment: @user64494. What you say in the above comment is quite differen from what you post in your question, and as it seems to answer your question, don't you think that you ought to post it as an answer rather than as a comment to my inquiry?

Comment: @m_goldberg, you are right.I made a mistake while writing   the output because of hindsigh.I edited the question accordingly.Lots of thanks for pointing it out